# Convert between child objects when using polymorphism?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I've got a problem that probably has to do with my design, but I'd like suggestions on how to improve it.
Essentially I have a parent class which has several child classes and I need to be able to convert between the child classes. However, the object to be converted in my current design uses polymorphism and a Parent class pointer. I do this because in the end which child class is used is determined by user input. I have figured out three ways to solve this problem:

1. Implement a separate "converter" class that can take each child class and convert it to another child class.
2. Declare virtual functions that converts each child class into other child classes. (This would create circular dependencies, which I don't think are a good idea...)
3. Include an enum data member in the objects that say which type they are so I can use a switch() statement when converting.

Are there other ways I should be thinking about it?
Here is some code that I think shows what I want to do.

```cpp
class Rotation
{
   public:
      void  Set();
      Vector Get();
      virtual void Rotate(float amount);
      virtual void SetFromQuaternion(Vector t_quaternion);
   private:
      Vector m_rotation;
}

class EulerAngles : Rotation
{
   public:
     void Rotate(float t_amount);
     void SetFromQuaternion(Vector t_quaternion);
}

class Quaternion: Rotation
{ 
  public:
     void Rotate(float t_amount);
     void SetFromQuaternion(Vector t_quaternion);//Just copies data
}
class RigidBody
{
  public:
     RigidBody(Rotation *t_rotation);
     Rotation GetRotation();
     void SetRotationFromQuaternion(Vector t_rotation) {m_rotation->SetRotationFromQuaternion(t_rotation);}
  private:
     std::unique_ptr<Rotation> *m_rotation;
}
int main()
{
   //Argument is based on user input file, but euler angles are used as an example
   Rigidbody body_1 = RigidBody(new EulerAngles());
   // I want to rotate using quaternions to avoid singularities, but then convert back to euler angles. So here's where I would convert. How should I do this?
   Quaternion temp_quaternion = (Quaternion)body_1.GetRotation();
   temp_quaternion.Rotate(amount);
   body_1.SetRotationFromQuaternion(temp_quaternion.Get());

   return;
}
```

Please note that my actual code is more complicated. My question is more to do with overall design "best practices." Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated: why do you have `std::unique_ptr<Rotation> *m_rotation;`? I think you're missing the idea behind `unique_ptr`.

Comment: In a sense, your rotation types all represent the exact same thing, like physical units. Is there one representation that you can use for everything? Supposing Euler angles work for all your use cases, why not make `RigidBody` accept only `EulerAngles`? Can you find a good reason why you need to support so many different forms of rotation simultaneously?

Comment: Is there some common unit between all the child classes that can represent all the different types? If so, the parent class can own that, and child classes can just be responsible for "display stuff". In this scenario, conversion could be something like EulerAngles(Quaternion q), where this could look something like the copy ctor

Comment: I tried to do this via edit, but stack is a bit stupid... Please add a linebreak before your enumeration (of questions), then it becomes much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: @jan.sende I got you covered. Note that up until 2000 rep, you can make edits, but they'll need to be approved by other users before being applied. After 2000 rep you can make immediate edits

Comment: @alterigel Thanks! The approving was not the problem, but I needed at least 6 characters for the edit...

Comment: Why do you use private inheritance?

Comment: It doesn’t seem to fit the purpose of your question that only the base class has any data members.

Comment: 1. Use one class for representing rotations, which can be converted to and from quaternions and Euler angles; 2. Let `RigidBody` handle its own rotations, without getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use polymorphism, the only thing you can do is get back the original type with a `dynamic_cast`. Example:

```
Rotation * r = new Quaternion;
Quaternion * q = dynamic_cast<Quaternion*>(r);
```

Now, if you want to convert one child class to another, I think you already know that the `dynamic_cast` will fail because the inner type is not `EulerAngles` but `Quaternion`.

To do this, as far as I know, you have no choice, you have to convert it yourself. In other word, write a converter function.

The idea to add a data member to give you the type of the object is quite good, but it is not enough. In any case, if you have a `Rotation*` which is in reality a `Quaternion*`, you will still need a converter to get a `EulerAngles*` from it.

Based on your idea, you could write:

```
// Here, I assumed that you will make the Rotation class pure virtual (I know that you didn't, but I think you should, and this only is an example)
enum class ROTATION_T {QUATERNION, EULERANGLES};

Rotation * convert(const Rotation * r)
{
   // We assume here than the class Rotation has the attribute rotation_type saying the type.
   if(r->rotation_type == ROTATION_T::QUATERNION)
   {
      // convert the Quaternion and return a EulerAngles*
   }
   else
   {
      // convert the EulerAngles and return a Quaternion*
   }
}
```

I will never pretend this is the only one solution to do it, but this is a way to do it.

I hope it can/will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your base problem is that you try to solve something using OOP, where absolutely no OO is needed! The goal of object orientation is:

- a division of concerns
- a description of class hierarchies

None of these points applies for your example! (Don't worry, nearly everyone starting with OO gets this wrong on their first tries...) This leads to convoluted code with unnecessary dependencies. For example:

- Why does your `RigidBody` store rotation information? It should just be a body, and a rotation should transform its underlying data.
- Why do all your classes have `SomethingFromQuaternion` function? If you cannot set it using `EulerAngles`, you should not add it to the name. Plus, the rotation is coupled to the `Quaternion`, it should not turn up as a member function.

**The correct way**

The right way to solve your problem is to implement a library of rotation types and functions to act on these types.

```
//We need a forward declaration of Quaternion in order to get the conversion
//operator working.
struct Quaternion;

//All of the classes (probably) can be struct as they do not save any private
//data members.
struct EulerAngles
{
    //members ...
    //constructors...
    //we declare a user defined conversion function
    explicit operator Quaternion() const;
};
struct Quaternion
{
    //members ...
    //constructors...
    //we declare a user defined conversion function
    explicit operator EulerAngles() const;
};
struct RigidBody
{
    //members ...
    //constructors...
    //we need a friend declaration to make our life easier
    friend auto inplace_rotate(RigidBody&,const Quaternion&) -> void;
};
//We actually need to define the conversion after the class declaration,
//or the compiler complains...
Quaternion::operator EulerAngles() const
{
    //add actual conversion here...
    return EulerAngles{};
}
EulerAngles::operator Quaternion() const
{
    //add actual conversion here...
    return Quaternion{};
}
//the actual rotation function
auto inplace_rotate(RigidBody& body, const Quaternion& rotation) -> void
{
    //implement...
    //notice the friend declaration in the RigidBody class, which gives us direct access.
    //(which we need in the case of private variables)
}
auto rotate(RigidBody body, const Quaternion& rotation) -> RigidBody
{
    //using the body without a reference, gives us the copy we need.
    //we are left with our rotation.
    inplace_rotate(body, rotation);
    return body;
}

int main()
{
   auto body = RigidBody{};
   //You need to get this from the user input.
   auto euler_rotation = EulerAngles{};
   //Using the user defined conversion operator.
   auto quaternion = static_cast<Quaternion>(euler_rotation);
   //Do the rotation.
   inplace_rotate(body, quaternion);

   return 0;
}
```

This approach does not seem to be that different to what you wrote, but it drastically reduced the amount of interconnectivity between the classes. Each class can now be viewed on its own and without consideration of all the others. Furthermore, it allows us to define conversions using the c++ way, with user defined converters. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) Pulling out the rotation function and making it standalone, allows us to easily extend it in one place (you do not need to update your body classes to make changes to it).

In addition, you could even define simple convenience overloads for your `EulerAngles`:

```
auto inplace_rotate(RigidBody& body, const EulerAngles& rotation)
{
    return inplace_rotate(body, static_cast<Quaternion>(rotation));
    //technically returning here is unnecessary because the return type is void,
    //but this allows you to consistenly change the inplace_function at any time
    //without needing to update the convenience funtion
}
auto rotate(RigidBody body, const EulerAngles& rotation)
{
    return inplace_rotate(body, static_cast<Quaternion>(rotation));
}
```

**Your actual problem?**

I guess the confusion arises from you trying to get the user input working for both `Quaternions` and `EulerAngles`. There are several approaches to solving this:

1. Write a user function which returns already rotated bodies.
2. Use `std::variant` (c++17) or the boost alternative.
3. Return to class inheritances.

I would recommend you to use either 1 or 2, however if this is not possible, you can do the following (3):

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

//An empty base class for rotation values.
struct Rotation {};

struct EulerAngles : Rotation
{
    //...
};
struct Quaternion : Rotation
{
    //...
};

auto parse_user_input(const std::string& input)
{
    if (input == "euler")
        return std::make_unique<Rotation>(EulerAngles{});
    else if (input == "quaternion")
        return std::make_unique<Rotation>(Quaternion{});
    else
        throw;
}
```